# Insert table into cell (excel)

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I need one cell that will contains sum of all items from another table. Is it possible to place that table into cell so I can expand and collapse table when I needed from that one cell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word, no, you can't. Even if you set a cell to be equal to the entire range on the table and set it to an array formula via *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* (for example: `={A1:B10}`) that cell would still evaluate to the top-left value of the table when used in formulas.

Just take the table and stick it in a hidden range or sheet.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible!
You need to use a named range, and you can insert your table as an object into a cell.
(tested in Excel 2010)

Comment: can you please share exactly how you did this?

Comment: An example or a link might have helped here. The answer raises further questions on how to do it.